# 401 Response after 1 hour of successfully uploading 380 previous video binary chunks

Tags: .net, oauth, youtube-api

I'm currently running into an issue where I successfully authenticate against OAuth with Google's helping libraries but after an hour of uploading, my authentication appears to fail and there doesn't appear to be anything I can do about it.

The source code is located at this location:

https://bitbucket.org/ramblingcoder/video-uploader/overview

I've used Log4Net to record the requests and responses from Google to try and debug the issue. I've attached the log file to the issue tracker at the following location:

https://bitbucket.org/ramblingcoder/video-uploader/issue/1/401-status-code-from-response-after-1-hour

I was originally calling "SignRequest" on each of my chunk upload calls but I found a post by another person that seemed to be getting the same issue. A responder said that the authentication on chunks wasn't required anymore so I removed that line from my code without any ill effects. Unfortunately, this didn't resolve my issue as I was still getting a 401 response after 1 hour. I've tried multiple times to see if there was a variation and it is always 1 hour.

In addition, before I removed the "SignRequest" function, I was checking for the 401 response and was refreshing my token. This appeared to be returning successfully, at least returning true, and I was still getting the issue.

Any help would be appreciated as I've been working on this issue for the past few days.

Edit:
I've made it past the one hour mark by changing the Google API version I used from V3 to V2. I've committed the changes accordingly to the repository above. It just appears that V3 is having issues with resumable uploads that last longer than one hour. I am 1 hour 10 minutes of a 8 hour upload and hopefully this issue won't popup again.

Edit:
No problems with the 8hour upload and a separate 4hour upload. Google V2 seems to be the way to go at the moment for resumable uploads for YouTube videos.

Answer (score 0):

This is a due to a server side bug.

See http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5124 for details.